# usage of not in negative sentences

Tags: word-usage

my name is Reza, I'm not a native English speaker. I'm wondering if this form of negative sentences is true in English? Because I see in novels, but this way is not explained in grammar books.

I saw not a single person. (instead of I did not see a single person.)

It seemed not to grasp its new surroundings.

It was a soft and gentle kiss, one not meant to lead beyond itself.

Try not to get so worked up about things.

Naoko was taking great care as she spoke not to touch on certain things.

Comment: If you see a sentence in an English novel that's written by a native English speaker, you don't need to wonder if it's grammatical. It is. Of course the grammar books don't explain much. _Not_ is the most common negative word; it can negate a predicate, whether verb, noun, or adjective, and that includes infinitives like the second sentence and last two examples. The first sentence is an alternative, as you point out; it's grammatical either way.

Comment: these sentences were from the novel Norwegian Wood by Haruki Murakami. translator I think is  Alfred Birnbaum. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could just as easily say 'I did not see a single person' and 'It did not seem to grasp its new surroundings'without a change in denotation. However, the connotation is slightly different:
'I did not see a single person' makes 'I' the important word and implies that someone else looking in the same place *could* have seen a single person, or they could have seen the same thing as the speaker saw. On the other hand, 'I (verb) not' makes 'single' the important word and implies that the speaker saw correctly. If it helps, think about how you could say 'I saw not a single person, but four'.